# how to add array to operators?

Tags: arrays, node.js, console.log, chalk

i just need a yes or a no and possibly a point in the right direction :)

i would like to know how would i be able even do this, chalk is just the same as colors.red, or colors.blue, its just chalk.red or chalk.blue but i would like to make an array that has the different colors that randomize for example, it would be console.log(chalk.arraycolor("this is a test"));

sorry for any problems i will cause, i just need a yes or a no and possibly a point in the right direction :)

[this is the code, sorry i could not upload the raw code as its on my raspberry pi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydosi.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think want you want is `chalk[rand]`.

Note that `foo["bar"]` is the equivalent of `foo.bar`.

Comment: thank you for answering my question, i knew it was something simple like that, anyway thanks man :)